# Animate text size with jQuery then return to previous state

Tags: jquery, css

I am playing around with animating text when clicked.

I have buttons with various classes that define size :

```
<div class="button-1">Click Me!</div>
<div class="button-2">Click Me!</div>
<div class="button-3">Click Me!</div>

.button-1 {font-size: 10px;}
.button-2 {font-size: 20px;}
.button-3 {font-size: 30px;}
```

Then when one is clicked it is animated to a bigger size.

```
    $('.button-1,.button-2,.button-3').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({fontSize: "40px" }, 1000 );
```

My question is I only want to have one big at a time and have all of the siblings return to their original size.  I see the animate function works by adding an inline style to the text, is there a way I can just delete out all of the inline styles appended to the clicked buttons siblings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works and looks much better...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-1,.button-2,.button-3').each(function() {

        $(this).data('original-size', $(this).css('fontSize'));

        $(this).click(function() {

            $(this).animate({
                fontSize: "40px"
            }, 1000);

            $(this).siblings().each(function() {

                var originalSize = $(this).data('original-size');

                if ($(this).css('fontSize') != originalSize) {

                    $(this).animate({
                        fontSize: originalSize
                    }, 500);
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmJMk/).

If you were lazy, you could also do...

```
$(this).siblings().removeAttr('style')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwwUr/1/).

This solution, however, is *flaky* and could lean to painful debugging if you or jQuery adds extra styles via the `style` attribute. I recommend you use the former code.

Comment: Your non-lazy solution is great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a shorter way to do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-1,.button-2,.button-3').click(function() {
        $('div').removeClass('button-4', 50);
        $(this).addClass('button-4', 100);

    });
});
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/nLnvY/2/

Comment: I didn't know you could pass a second argument there. +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: I like it, but why does this work? The jQuery API page for the addClass() method doesn't cite the availability of a second parameter. Is the approach a hack/side effect, or is it officially supported? See: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/